# Displaying names of related entities in a table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many

I have a model with two entities in a many-to-many relationship. I also needed to store extra information about the join, so I have used a custom join arrangement. The model is as follows -

**Disease Model**

```
public class Disease
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 DiseaseID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Disease")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string DiseaseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App.Models.Medicine.MedicineToDisease> MedicineToDisease { get; set; }       
}
```

**Medicine Model**

```
public class Medicine
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 MedicineID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Generic Name")]
    public string Medicine_Generic_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<App.Models.Medicine.MedicineToDisease> MedicineToDisease { get; set; }
```

**Join Table -**

```
public class MedicineToDisease
{
    public int MedicineToDiseaseId { get; set; }

    public int MedicineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Medicine Medicine { get; set; }

    public int DiseaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Disease.Disease Disease { get; set; }

    -- Other Information Fields related to the join --
}
```

I have created a listing view model which displays a list of all medicines. I want to display a **DISTINCT** list of all diseases for which there is any information in the join table above. Here is the ViewModel so far -

```
public class MedicineListViewModel
    {
        public Int32 MedicineID { get; set; }
        public string MedicineName { get; set; }
        public string AssociatedDiseases { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller code that queries the information is as follows -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var model = db.Medicine.Select(u => new MedicineListViewModel
            {
                MedicineID = u.MedicineID,
                MedicineName = u.Medicine_Generic_Name + " (" + u.Medicine_Trade_Name + ")",
                NoOfTimesFree = u.Medicine_TimesFree,
                AssociatedDiseases = db.MedicineToDisease.Where(m=>m.MedicineId == u.MedicineID).Select(s => s.Disease.DiseaseName).Distinct().ToList().ToString() 
            }).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMsg"] = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think - `AssociatedDiseases` property should be `List<string>` rather than only string? Or you want comma seperated name list for `AssociatedDiseases` property

Comment: Yes, ultimately it has to be a list which can be displayed in a column in a for..each loop. However, I tried to simplify the implementation temporarily.

Comment: But in your  `MedicineListViewModel` class `AssociatedDiseases` property is string instead of `List<string>`. Is it typo or what ??

Comment: No. Its not a typo because the code I have now is trying to simply get all the related disease names in a single string. As I said eventually it will have to be a List<string>.

Comment: I get this error : 
[System.NotSupportedException] = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Try this code - `AssociatedDiseases = string.Join(", ", db.MedicineToDisease.Where(m => m.MedicineId == u.MedicineID).AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Disease.DiseaseName).Distinct().ToArray())` and also changed at this line - `var model = db.Medicine.AsEnumerable().Select(u => new MedicineListViewModel...`

Comment: That works. Wonderful. As a last step, I need to link each of the related disease names retrieved by including the MedicineID and DiseaseID in the querystring. I guess since this is a related entity to the Medicine and Disease tables, we already have access to the MedicineID and DiseaseID properties. The question now is how to link it up and display the whole set of items. Please suggest.

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana : Any suggestions to my last comment?